# react-admin getList and pagination issue as even header has been set and displayed in image attached

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin

In follows, my code is attached and needs to paginate but can#t get a result, I followed all guidelines, can anybody help me, please

```
const allEmployees = async (req, res) => {
  var query = "select * from tbl_personal";
  const allEmployeesHeader = await executeQuery(query);
  res.header('X-Total-Count',  `employees 0-10/${allEmployeesHeader.length}`)
  res.json(allEmployeesHeader);
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first, have to get variables from URL coming from reacting admin front end and then these variables send to database query for having the desired pagination, search and sorting. This all should be done inside node js API

```
 `const path = url.parse(req.url).path;
  console.log("url", path);
  let Page = req.query.range;
  console.log("page", Page);
  let SortingResource = req.query.sort;
  let orderedByWhatType = JSON.parse(SortingResource);
  console.log("orderedByWhatType", orderedByWhatType);
  let orderedByWhat = orderedByWhatType[0];
  let sortAscOrDes = orderedByWhatType[1];
  console.log("ordered By What", orderedByWhat);
  console.log("sortAscOrDes", sortAscOrDes);
  let PageCurrent = JSON.parse(Page);
  console.log("Page array ", PageCurrent);
  //console.log("Page index", PageIndex);
  let PerPageATZeroIndex = parseInt(PageCurrent[1]);
  console.log("PerPage", typeof PerPageATZeroIndex);

  let PageIndex = PageCurrent[0];
  //// function for range////
  const range = (start, end, length = end - start + 1) =>
    Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => start + i);

  ///////function for range///
  TotalRows = range(PageIndex, PerPageATZeroIndex).length;
  console.log("i am range", range(PageIndex, PerPageATZeroIndex).length);

  let OFFSET = PageIndex;
  let till = OFFSET + PerPageATZeroIndex;
  let FilterInput = req.query.filter;
  FilterArray = JSON.parse(FilterInput);
  console.log("Filter", FilterArray);
  FilterSource = Object.keys(FilterArray);
  FilterText = Object.values(FilterArray)[0];
  FilterText = Object.values(null || FilterArray)[0];

  if (FilterText == undefined) {
    console.log("Oooops, am Undefined");
    let query = `  SELECT * FROM tbl_Personal WHERE shortname LIKE ('%')         
    ORDER BY pnr ${sortAscOrDes}
     OFFSET ${PageIndex} ROWS FETCH NEXT ${TotalRows} ROWS ONLY `;

    let numRows = `SELECT * FROM tbl_Personal`;
    const paginationEmployees = await executeQuery(query);
    const numRowsCount = await executeQuery(numRows);
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Total-Count");
    res.header(
      "X-Total-Count",
      `pagination ${OFFSET} - ${till}/${numRowsCount.length}`
    );
    res.json(paginationEmployees);
  }`
```