# React-admin from marmalab Node js Api for pagination, filtering sorting and setting range

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin

I would like to ask for help in writing node js API for filtering, pagination, and sorting in React-ADMIN framework. I have written my own data provider and set header well but still not successful in getting pagination sorting or filtering functional

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself and I was missing to write all pagination, sorting, and filtering on my backend API side, after writing it on the backend and matching variables with react admin get list front end API, successful to get my desired result. further details explained inside [react-admin getList and pagination issue as even header has been set and displayed in image attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73033315/react-admin-getlist-and-pagination-issue-as-even-header-has-been-set-and-display)